# Set column status based on a match between two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

T1

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

T2

```
id status
1  Yes
2  Yes
3  Yes
4  Yes
5  No
6  No
```

If I find id matched in both the tables, the status should be updated as Yes else No

Comment: Do you use MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag only the one you actually use.

Comment: SQL Server. Just edited

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a `CASE` expression and `EXITS` with a correlated subquery that checks for the existence of a row in the other table.

```
UPDATE t2
       SET status = CASE
                      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                                          FROM t1
                                          WHERE t1.id = t2.id) THEN
                        'Yes'
                      ELSE
                        'No'
                    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update using a `LEFT JOIN`. If the `t1.id` is null, then there is no match, and you can set it to `No`. Otherwise, set it to yes.

```sql
UPDATE t2
  SET t2.Status = CASE WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' 
                       ELSE 'No' 
                  END
  FROM t2
  LEFT JOIN t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery within the `CASE`

```sql
UPDATE t2
  SET t2.Status = CASE WHEN t2.id IN (SELECT id FROM t1) THEN 'Yes' 
                       ELSE 'No' 
                  END
```